# bash: How to round/floor/ceiling non-decimals thousands number?

Tags: bash, rounding, floor, ceil

lets say I have this number here `100675`

how to turn it into `101000`

all the solution I have found on google are solving decimals number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `bash` shell is able to do calculations internally, such as with the following transcript:

```
pax:~> for x in 100675 100499 100500 100999 101000; do
...:~>     ((y = (x + 500) / 1000 * 1000))
...:~>     echo "    $x becomes $y"
...:~> done
    100675 becomes 101000
    100499 becomes 100000
    100500 becomes 101000
    100999 becomes 101000
    101000 becomes 101000
```

This statement, `((y = (x + 500) / 1000 * 1000))`, first adds 500 to make the otherwise-truncating integer division by 1,000 into a *rounding* division, then re-multiplies it by 1,000.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a weird function, but here goes a rough version that might be what you need. At least this could be a starting point.

```
# in:
#  $1 - the number to round
#  $2 - the 10 power to round at. Defaults to 3 (i.e. 1000)
# output:
#  The rounded number
roundPow()
{
  local n="$1"
  local pow="${2:-3}"
  local div="$((10 ** pow))"
  echo "$((((n + div / 2) / div) * div))"
}
```

This is very rough around the edges, it's not validating parameters, etc, but should give you a baseline.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but sorry i prefer paxdiablo's answer because it is so lightweight and just works

Comment: Yep, no worries.